# Why and how do I prevent a blank page when the Keycloak server is not available? Vue, Keycloak, Quasar

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, keycloak, quasar-framework

Im relative new to vue and i am trying to connect my Vue Application based on [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) with Keycloak. I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.icod.de/2021/02/25/keycloak-js-client-with-quasar/) and used the [dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js](https://github.com/dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js) library.

Everything works in case, the Keycloak server is reachable.

Now, of course, it is possible that the server is unreachable for some reason, such as DNS problems. In this case i got a blank white page instead of showing the page without working login button. With using the onInit Option from the library i can catch the error but very lately and still the page is blank.

How can the page still loaded and show content just without a working login button if the keycloak server is unreachable/not able to process my request?

```
//keycloak.ts
import VueKeyCloak from '@dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js'
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import { VueKeycloakInstance } from '@dsb-norge/vue-keycloak-js/dist/types';
import { api } from 'boot/axios';
import {InternalAxiosRequestConfig} from 'axios';

export default boot(async ({ app}) => {
  function registerTokenInterceptor () {
    app.provide('keycloak', app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak);

    api.interceptors.request.use((config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
      if (app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak.authenticated) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak.token}`
      }
      return config
    }, error => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }) //null, { synchronous: true })
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    app.use(VueKeyCloak, {
      init: {
        checkLoginIframe: false, // or 'login-required'
        flow: 'standard',
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        pkceMethod: 'S256',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-check-sso.html'
      },
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
        realm: 'master',
        clientId: 'testclient',
      },
      logout: {
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:9000',
      },
      onReady() {
        registerTokenInterceptor()
        resolve()
      }
    })
  })
})

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {

  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
    $keycloak: VueKeycloakInstance
  }
}
```